# Wrapping a function to Delay the Call of that function? (Deleting a Task in React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, onclick

I'm currently following along CS50 Harvard's Beyond React Course and I'm currently practicing making a Todo List and Deleting a Task by clicking on a button. One thing I don't understand is how for deleting a task, we don't want to immediately call deleteTask(i) on the click of a button because as the lecturer quotes, "That is the result of a function, and that is not what we want to do." Instead he wraps the deleteTask function in another function with no arguments, and I don't understand the difference between my version and his version, and what he means by result.

This is the deleteTask

```
deleteTask = (index) => {
        this.setState(state => {

          const tasks = [...state.tasks];
          tasks.splice(index, 1);
          return {
            tasks: tasks
            };
          })
      }
```

This is what was recommended within the onClickButton:

```
               <ul>
                {this.state.tasks.map((task, i) => 
                    <li key={i}>
                      {task}
                      <button onClick={() => this.deleteTask(i)}>Delete</button>
                    </li>
                  )}
              </ul>
```

But this is what I had:

```
               <ul>
                {this.state.tasks.map((task, i) => 
                    <li key={i}>
                      {task}
                      <button onClick={this.deleteTask(i)}>Delete</button>
                    </li>
                  )}
              </ul>
```

Comment: You want a function as parameter. The way you code it, is executing the function, not referencing it...

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way

```
<button onClick={i => this.deleteTask}>Delete</button>
```

you can use the function filter and afterward you need use the `setState` function:

```
deleteTask =(itemToDelete)=>{
    const deleted = this.state.tasks.filter(s=> s.id !== itemToDelete.id);
    this.setState({
      tasks: deleted
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick={this.deleteTask(i)}>Delete</button>
```

When you do this, you're calling the function every time your component renders, when in fact you should be calling it only when the button is clicked. The parentheses indicates that you're executing the function, where as you only need to reference it.

Please take a look at this link below to understand the concept better:
https://upmostly.com/tutorials/react-onclick-event-handling-with-examples